# Convert Custom Struct to Uint in solidty

Tags: struct, solidity-0.8.x

I'm unable to convert Uint/bytes32 back to my `struct Jury`

Here is the struct im trying to convert to bytes32.

```
struct Jury {
    address userAddress; //20 bytes
    uint16 credibilityScore; //2 bytes
    uint32 count; //4 bytes
    bool exists; //1 bytes
}
```

From my understand, the struct should fit within Uint/bytes32 size.

The method that failed:

```
 function toJury(uint256 _data) public pure returns (Jury memory _jury) {
        bytes memory data = abi.encodePacked(_data);

        (
            _jury.userAddress,
            _jury.credibilityScore,
            _jury.count,
            _jury.exists
        ) = abi.decode(data, (address, uint16, uint32, bool));
    }
```

The method I've used to convert from `Jury` to `Bytes/Uint`:

```
  function toUint(Jury memory _jury) external pure returns (uint256) {
        bytes memory _bytes = abi.encodePacked(
            _jury.userAddress,
            _jury.credibilityScore,
            _jury.count,
            _jury.exists
        );
        bytes memory result = new bytes(32);
        for (uint16 i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            if (i < _bytes.length) {
                result[i] = _bytes[i];
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return uint256(bytes32(result));
    }
```

Note: updated code, paste incorrectly previously

Comment: I think you mistakenly pasted the same code twice - both the packing function that failed and the one following it are identical

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I cast my data to `uint256` then to `bytes32` in order to perform *bits shifting*. Might not be the most efficient, but it was easy for me to understand.

```
 function juryToUint(Jury memory _jury) internal pure returns (uint) {
        bytes32 userAddressData = bytes32(uint256(uint160(_jury.userAddress)));
        bytes32 credibilityScoreData = bytes32(uint256(_jury.credibilityScore));
        bytes32 countData = bytes32(uint256(_jury.count));

        bytes32 userAddressBytes = userAddressData << 56;
        bytes32 credibilityScoreBytes = credibilityScoreData << 40;
        bytes32 countBytes = countData << 8;
        bytes32 existsBytes = bytes32(_jury.exists ? uint256(1) : uint256(0));

        return
            uint(
                userAddressBytes |
                    credibilityScoreBytes |
                    countBytes |
                    existsBytes
            );
    }
```

```
function uintToJury(
        uint256 _data
    ) internal pure returns (Jury memory jury) {
        bytes32 data = bytes32(_data);

        jury.userAddress = address(uint160(uint256((data >> 56))));
        jury.credibilityScore = uint16(uint256(data >> 40));
        jury.count = uint32(uint256(data >> 8));
        jury.exists = uint256(bytes32(_data & 0xff)) == 1;

        return jury;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your last 32 bytes of params.
[image]